# How to set different h4 and a:hover on certain pages

Tags: html, css

So site uses text underline on mouse hover accross the website but on one page I must set mouse hover as color change only, without underline decoration.

```
<div class="hcolor">
 <a href="#"><h4>Custom Text</h4></a>
</div>
```

In CSS i have tried:

```
.hcolor h4 a:hover{
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 }
```

But this doest work as standard settings still override these and link keeps getting underlined.

Comment: CSS Cascades in this order:
Browser default,
External style sheet,
Internal style sheet (in the head section),
Inline style (inside an HTML element),
So to make sure you're affecting the right element with your CSS, try putting it in the head of the page as a test.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.hcolor a:hover h4 {
  color: #fff !important;
  text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

Comment: oh, the selector was wrong, you should do "a:hover h4" or put the anchor INSIDE the h4 tag

Answer (score 0):

CSS generally goes down from parent element to the child element. You css would go to the element with class `.hcolor` and then would go and see for the element `h4` and after that in that element it would go and see for a child `a` hyperlink, now when you hover over to it. The CSS would be applied.

But since there is no tree which matches this, you either need to change the HTML or CSS.

```
<div class="hcolor">
 <h4>
  <a href="#">Custom Text</a>
 </h4>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/B9Bt5/1/ (Change in HTML)

So either change your HTML as the one above, or change your CSS to:

```
.hcolor a h4:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/B9Bt5/ (Change in CSS)

Comment: I've tried your CSS change and it doesn't work, it stills udnerline.

Comment: Yes, because you're using `text-decoration: underline` for hyperlink and not h4, so please change the HTML!

Comment: HTML change won't change the string of the HTML and your output will be same but the TEXT_DECORATION will be removed..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Code**

```
<div class="hcolor">
<h4> <a href="#">Custom Text</a></h4>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h4 a:link {
 text-decoration:none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your CSS declaration has priority over declarations already specified in the template. Since only one page has to incorporated this change, go ahead and specify to the finest CSS.

Example

```
div.hcolor a:hover h4 {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Otherwise, there might be a template CSS that has priority. Use Inspect Element to check which CSS rule is applying.

Answer (score -1):

Your css is wrong. Try:

```
.hcolor a:hover{
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 }
```

P.S.
Why do you use an `<h4>` tag inside an `<a>` tag? Just style your `<a>` with css

P.P.S.
Ok let me explain better: my suggest is to remove `<h4>`and give the style you want to `<a>` with css.
So, your html code should be:

```
<div class="hcolor">
 <a href="#">Custom Text</a>
</div>
```

In my opinion there is no sense using another tag inside `<a>` when you can give the style you want with css.

Comment: Why? What is wrong? This works as well. The P.S. was just a suggestion.

Comment: I am not talking about the code brother! :) I am talking about the suggestion :)

Comment: So, it's not possible give suggestion? Let me understand.... Explain why with a suggestion, this answer is not useful.

Comment: No no, it actually is possible to give suggestion, but it is not possible to suggest something that is already present..He is doing the same..

Comment: I suggest to him to remove tag `<h4>`, he is not doing the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45054/discussion-between-maurelio79-and-afzaal-ahmad-zeeshan)

Answer (score -1):

Hi,

```
    a.hcolor:hover, .hcolor:hover {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

This css code will work

**Update : 
You said you weren't working. You sure you said the right thing? I think we didn't understand the problem**